# Where would I ask a question about using WolframAlpha?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

I have a question about using WolframAlpha, but I'm not sure which site I should ask on. My question is "Does Wolfram Alpha support [Knuth's Arrow Notation](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knuth%27s_up-arrow_notation)?".

**Would it be more appropriate to ask about WolframAlpha on [Mathematica](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/wolfram-alpha-queries), [Mathematics](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/wolfram-alpha), [Web Applications](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/wolfram-alpha), or [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/wolframalpha)?**

All four sites have tags for WolframAlpha, meaning that certain questions could be at least somewhat on-topic for each site.

Comment: Could you tell us exactly what the question is?

Comment: @gnat I'm not sure I understand why this would be a dupe?

Comment: How can this be a duplicate if the older question asks something different and the answer is not found there??

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> meaning that certain questions could be at least somewhat on-topic

The existence of a tag does not mean that. Off-topic questions need tags too. A tag attached to off-topic questions continues to exist unless all of those questions are deleted or retagged, which may never happen.

Anyway, let's read those tag pages:

- **[Mathematica](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/wolfram-alpha-queries)**: "Use this for questions about calling Wolfram Alpha from Mathematica. Questions about Wolfram Alpha itself are off-topic."  I think this is pretty clear.
- **[Mathematics](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/wolfram-alpha)**: "For mathematical questions related to the usage of Wolfram Alpha."  I think this means questions like  "Wolfram Alpha tells me that this integral evaluates to 0, but I'm looking for a proof of that".
- **[Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/wolframalpha)** tag usage guidance is lacking in guidance, but reading the questions one can infer that to be on-topic, they ought to involve a program consuming Wolfram Alpha API.
- **[Web Applications](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/wolfram-alpha)** is the right site for questions about Wolfram Alpha usage such as "Does Wolfram Alpha support Knuth's Arrow Notation?".

That said, Wolfram Alpha is pretty opaque in how and why it does what it does; there's a good chance that if you don't see an intuitive way to do something with it, others don't see it either.